# How to replace non diagonal elements of matrix by row?

Tags: r

I would like to replace non diagonal elements of matrix with a
sequence of numbers.
I managed to write this:

```
mat[outer(1:nrows(mat), 1:nrows(mat), function(i,j) j!=i)] <- seq(1:182)
```

But it fills the number by column. I would not like to use the
transpose function as I have specific row name which I would like to
keep.

**Example**

So if I have a matrix *m*

```
m <- matrix(NA, nrow=5, ncol=5, dimnames=list(letters[1:5], NULL))
m
#   [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
# a   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
# b   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
# c   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
# d   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
# e   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
```

How can I add a sequence to the non-diagonals while keeping the rownames of the original matrix: expected output

```
#   [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
# a   NA    1    2    3    4
# b    5   NA    6    7    8
# c    9   10   NA   11   12
# d   13   14   15   NA   16
# e   17   18   19   20   NA
```

Comment: @akrun Will you manage to help me?

Comment: the `t` option is more direct, can't u just rename the row name (if I understand it correctly)

Comment: its the dim name, which I like to keep, is it possible?

Comment: The dimnames can be changed with `dimnames(m1)<-`

Comment: Rob, I have tried to add an example reproducible example that seems to describe your problem - please edit it needs it.

Comment: Akrun probably has a more concise approach but this should work... `m[row(m) != col(m)] <- 1:20 ; out <- t(m); dimnames(out) <- rev(dimnames(out))` (hat nod to previous comments)

Comment: @user20650 I'm not good at this. When I run dimnames(m) I get
$from
 [1] "State 1"  "State 2"  "State 3"  "State 4"  "State 5"  "State 6"
"State 7"  "State 8"  "State 9"
[10] "State 10" "State 11" "State 12" "State 13" "State 14"

$to
 [1] "State 1"  "State 2"  "State 3"  "State 4"  "State 5"  "State 6"
"State 7"  "State 8"  "State 9"
[10] "State 10" "State 11" "State 12" "State 13" "State 14". How to keep it?

Comment: I got it: 
tmp<-dimnames(tmat2)
names(tmp)<-c("to", "from")
dimnames(tmat)<-tmp

Comment: @user20650 Thx, how can I +1 you?

Comment: Can you check my updated post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can try

```
mat[lower.tri(mat, diag=FALSE)|upper.tri(mat, diag=FALSE)] <- 1:182
```

Or

```
mat[!diag(ncol(mat))] <- 1:182
```

Using a small example in OP's post

```
m[!diag(ncol(m))] <- 1:20
out <- t(m)
dimnames(out) <- rev(dimnames(out))
```

Used `rev` from @user20650's comments

Comment: Thx, but it does the same work as my code. I need the numbers to be filled by row and not by column.

Comment: @RobM You haven't provided a small example or an expected output.

Comment: @RobM The `t(mat)` gives the exact output.

Comment: "I would not like to use the transpose function as I have specific row name which I would like to keep."

Comment: @Pascal Take a breath.  I may or may not delete it.  You can do your childish activity.